# Where can ask my question about "if an Android tablet can be defined as PC"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked my question "Can we refer Android Tablets as PC?" on Super User, but it was put on hold.

This is my question:

> As we know PC is a patented/special form of computer by IBM. As an alternative there is Mac (although getting closer to PC everyday). I see some people/sites call Android Tablets as PC. Is it correct? If yes, then what about iPad? How do we categorize it? Any idea or resource on that?

I could not find better place in the Stack Exchange Network. So where do I ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea or resource on that?

Asking for recommending resource is off topic.

> Is it correct? If yes, then what about iPad? How do we categorize it?

Primarily opinion based questions are off topic.

In short, this question doesn't fit in any of the SE site.

If you are talking about the legal issues in calling Tablet as PC which is trademarked by IBM, you can check the how to ask and on topic sections of [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Quora... is for opinions.

Comment: yes @iBug that's right. This question will fit on Quora

Comment: Everything that doesn't fit here at SE will fit on Quora :-)